# Will our beta label be removed?

Tags: discussion, beta

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293) and [Freelancing is graduating](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/25010) and [Retrocomputing is graduating](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/18437) and [Economics is graduating](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2161/20029), I'm curious if Engineering will be too?

Answer (score 5):

## Yes!

We got the same notice that the other sites received. We were waiting for an official announcement from the company before mentioning it here, but obviously the cat is out of the bag.

##### What to expect

The biggest change for our site will be that a round of moderator elections will occur sometime in 2022. If you have a desire to be a moderator, start thinking about it now.

The other changes are still welcome, but will not generally affect the day to day running of the site.